# Can't use second database with Angular 8 on Firebase hosting

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular8, angularfire

I'm developing a frontend to use it on Firebase hosting and I have two databases(RTDB) in my Firebase project: DB1 and DB2. I want to use DB2(which is not the default DB) in my project and I changed my DB URL in my Firebase config object but when I write something to DB, it's still writing it to DB1(default DB) and I can't even read data. It says permission_denied.

And I have some rules for security but I'm able to read data in my old project which is developed with pure JS but in this one, I can't even access to DB2.

I initialized my config like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, LogInComponent, DashboardComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, DbService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

And I'm trying to read data like this:

`this.fireDatabase.database.ref("users/userId/private/email");`

And also I'm pretty sure I'm authenticated because I'm checking auth state and then reading the data and this flow is chained. So, I'm stuck to this for almost 4 hours and no solution... Can anybody help?